# django sendfile with python 3.x vs 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am getting error with below code when I switched my django project from python 2.7 to Python 3.4. In python 2.7 everything works fine.

```
from sendfile import sendfile
return sendfile(request, myfile, attachment=True, attachment_filename=filename)
```

If i try to run above code I am getting below error.

```
    return sendfile(request, myfile, attachment=True, attachment_filename=filename)
TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I gone through some python 3.4 documentation and try different other options as well.

Try 1:

```
        return sendfile(*(request, myfile), **{'attachment':True, 'attachment_filename':filename})
    TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

return sendfile(*(request, myfile), **{'attachment':True, 'attachment_filename':filename}
```

)

Try 2:

```
    return sendfile(request, myfile, True, filename)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type WSGIRequest)
```

I am new to python 3.4 and django both. Please let me know what wrong in above?

Comment: which sendfile package have you installed? The python's or Django's ?

Comment: Also, why are you using `*(foo,bar)` instead of `foo, bar` and `**{foo:bar,baz:mumble}` instead of `foo=bar,baz=mumble`.

Comment: @Karthik- I am using django sendfile. I have imported it like  "from sendfile import sendfile". Is i am doing something wrong. I have followed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sendfile. 
working.

Comment: @ppperry- please go through question. I have first tried with the same only. Which works well in python 2.7. But with Python 3.4 it is not

Comment: @karthikr - I have installed django-sendfile as well by by default when i am using sendfile it is using sendfile function defined in pysendfile.How to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments infer, you get this error if you've installed the `pysendfile` package instead of the `django-sendfile` package.

1. Enter your virtual environment if you have one.
2. Look to see what packages are installed: `pip freeze`
3. If `pysendfile` is installed and `django-sendfile` is not installed, run: `pip uninstall pysendfile` and `pip install django-sendfile`